# Azure authentication together with OAuth authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, azure, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have to find a sollution for a problem. So I am developing website, and I am stuck with authentication. First of all, we are using Azure Active Directory for user storage. So I found [WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet), and made it work for my needs. It works fine so far. But now I have to implement also external logins (facebook, twitter etc.) So I commented out all previous work for the time I am working with this task. I had to rewrite some UserManager and UserStore classes, but got it to work. I can log in with facebook. But now, when I need to join both of these logins together, they are not working. It seems, that they are making conflicts inside the framework. Facebook login requires `app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);`, but the moment I turn this on, azure login stops working. If I comment this out, azure login works, facebook doesnt. Could anyone give me some help to fix this? I will provide my `Startup.Auth.cs`

```
using System;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using ClearRoadmapWeb.LoginProviderHelpers;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClearRoadmapWeb
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
                }
            );

            app.CreatePerOwinContext<AzureIdentityUserManager>(AzureIdentityUserManager.Create); //For Faceook
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<AzureIdentitySignInManager>(AzureIdentitySignInManager.Create); //For Facebook

            #region FacebookOptions
            //app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            FacebookAuthenticationOptions facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "fb appId",
                AppSecret = "fb appSecret"
            };
            facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            facebookOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                {
                    foreach (var x in context.User)
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(x.Key, x.Value.ToString()));
                    }
                    //Get the access token from FB and store it in the database and use FacebookC# SDK to get more information about the user
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                }
            };

            #endregion
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default OpenIdConnect authentication mode is active. This means oidc will always try and handle the authorize. What works for me is to issue a direct challenge as inside a controller method, as in:

HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge("FaceBook");

This is after coding Startup_Auth as:

```
    public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        CookieAuthenticationExtensions.UseCookieAuthentication(
            app,
            new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "FaceBook",
            });

        FacebookAuthenticationExtensions.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            app,
            new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = "...",
                AppSecret = "...",
                AuthenticationType = "FaceBook",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "FaceBook",
            });

        CookieAuthenticationExtensions.UseCookieAuthentication(
        app,
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "OpenIdConnect",
        });

        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationExtensions.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            app,
            new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "OpenIdConnect",
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                ClientId = "...",
                Authority = "...",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "OpenIdConnect"
            });
```

You will need to make sure when you want to 'switch' identities between AAD and FB, you clear the existing identity by sign-out or clearing the current cookies.

Comment: OpenID worked, but for facebook, I had to change `"FaceBook"` to `"Facebook"`. But then, after facebook login, it loops me into `https://localhost:44300/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Facebook&error=access_denied&error=access_denied...&error=access_denied...` (adding `&error=access_denied` every time)